# regex: matching a repeating sequence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to construct a regular expression that will match a repeating DNA sequence of 2 characters. These characters can be the same.

The regex should match a repeating sequence of 2 characters at least 3 times and, here are some examples:

regex should match on:

- ATATAT
- GAGAGAGA
- CCCCCC

and should not match on:

- ACAC
- ACGTACGT

So far I've come up with the following regular expressions:

```
[ACGT]{2}
```

this captures any sequence consisting of exactly two characters (A, C,  G or T). Now I want to repeat this pattern at least three times, so I tried the following regular expressions:

```
[ACGT]{2}{3,}
([ACGT]{2}){3,}
```

Unfortunately, the first one raises a 'multiple repeat' error (Python), while the second one will simply match any sequence with 6 characters consisting of A, C, G and T.

Is there anyone that can help me out with this regular expression?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could perhaps make use of backreferences.

```
([ATGC]{2})\1{2,}
```

`\1` is the backreference referring to the first capture group and will be what you have captured.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wC2cF1)

Comment: Will match ACAC (ACACACAC certainly) - not downvoting because I have no idea what the OP wants

Comment: @AlecTeal Entire expression will not match match `ACAC`. :)

Comment: @thefourtheye so the OP wants to reject only ACAC? This sounds like a job for simple if statements in that case, the comment stays because I am not convinced it does not apply.

Comment: @AlecTeal He wants to match any two letter combination of `AGCT` and that should be repeated atleast twice.

Comment: Cases like `AAATTTAAATTTAAA` aren't caught by this pattern.

Comment: @MichaelMolter  Correct, and per the requirements, it should not.

Answer (score 0):

One:

```
(AT){3}
```

Two

```
(GA){4}
```

Three

```
C{6}
```

Combining them!

```
(C{6}|(GA){4}|(AT){3})
```

Comment: He wants to match something like `ACACAC` or any combination of letters in `AGCT`

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't really follow

Comment: He wants to match patterns like, `ACACAC`, `ACACACAC`, `GCGCGC`

Comment: @thefourtheye then why is RedNaw's answer not the accepted one?

Comment: Because he deleted it?

Comment: @thefourtheye it basically went `(..)\1{2,}`

Comment: Yup I can see that :) `..` will match anything, right? OP wants to match only the letters in `AGCT`

Comment: @thefourtheye these are DNA bases, there are only 4 letters, so dot matches any letters, and the 4 in the input are a subset of that, a closed subset...

Comment: Correct. He wants to match only those letters, but `..` will match any character.

Comment: @thefourtheye you're being silly now, the strings this regex is used on will only have 4 symbols, `A` `G` `C` and `T` - there wont be any `b` or `B` or spaces, thus the dot worked.

Comment: @Jerry you can't have T in RNA sequences, but these libraries deal in 4 bases (AGCT) and convert as needed, storing 4 possibilities requires just 2 bits, then a codon is 6 bits and so forth.